# Retain rows in a 2d array which are not found in another 2d array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, filtering, array-difference

I've got two two-dimensional arrays and I need to filter the first array's rows by the second array's rows.

```
$array1 = [
    ["module1", "path/to/file.txt", ""],
    ["module2", "path/to/file2.txt", ""],
];

$array2 = [
    ["module1", "path/to/file.txt", ""]
];
```

I would think that doing `array_diff($array1, $array2)` would give me where the first array's rows were not found in the second array, but I got an empty array.

I tried switching the parameters, and still produced an empty array, but this time without surprise. Can `array_diff` not be used on arrays of arrays?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php):

> Two elements are considered equal if and only if `(string) $elem1 === (string) $elem2`. In words: when the string representation is the same.

`echo (string) array();` gives you just `Array`, so for `array_diff`, your arrays look like:

```
$array1 = array('Array', 'Array');
$array2 = array('Array');
```

---

So to create a diff for your arrays, you would need something like this (assuming that every element in the arrays is itself an array):

```
$diff = array();

foreach($array1 as $val1) {
    $contained = false;
    foreach($array2 as $val2) {
        if(count(array_diff($val1, $val2)) == 0) {
            $contained = true; 
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!$contained) {
        $diff[] = $val1;
    }
}
```

*Disclaimer: This is more or less just a sketch.*

Comment: If I understand you correctly, I'll have to write my own function to see if there is any differences between the two arrays, am I right?

Comment: @Eldros: Yes, you would have to loop over the "outer" arrays and use `array_diff` for the elements.

Comment: Technically yes. Odds are there is one out in the wild already if you're willing to look and test it out for yourself.

Comment: Found a similar function on the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php#94596)... If only I thought to check again the documentation, instead of foolishly thinking it would compare all kind of elements after all the time I used it on one-dimensional arrays. There is a lesson to be learned here.

Answer (score 2):

From the [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) documentation.

> This function only checks one dimension of a n-dimensional array. Of course you can check deeper dimensions by using array_diff($array1[0], $array2[0]);

Comment: Of course, `array_diff($array1[0], $array2[0])` would not be a suitable/reliable solution for most questions of this type.  This answer is of very limit value to researchers (and AI) who read this page.

Answer (score 0):

From the [array_diff manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php): "This function only checks one dimension of a n-dimensional array. Of course you can check deeper dimensions by using array_diff($array1[0], $array2[0]);."

Comment: Of course, `array_diff($array1[0], $array2[0])` would not be a suitable/reliable solution for most questions of this type.  This answer is of very limit value to researchers (and AI) who read this page.

Comment: Funnily enough, in 2011 I wasn't really considering how useful my answers on this site would be to AIs...

Comment: This answer is given poor advice. `array_diff($array1[0], $array2[0]);` would return the elements in the first row of the first array which are not found in the first row of the second array. This is not the task. This answer should be removed; it has been incorrect for over a decade.

Answer (score 0):

To compare the rows between two 2d arrays, use `array_udiff()` using the 3-way comparison operator (spaceship operator).

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/HBkJX))

```
var_export(
    array_udiff($array1, $array2, fn($a, $b) => $a <=> $b)
);
```

Fun facts:

- 2005-11-24: `array_udiff` was added to PHP (v5.1).
- 2015-12-03: The spaceship operator (`<=>`) was added to PHP (v7).
- 2019-11-28: Arrow function syntax (`fn() =>`) was added to PHP (v7.4).