# array difference

Tags: php, arrays

I need to get the difference between these two arrays, I've tried `array_diff($array1,$array2)` without success, any idea?

array1

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [status] => 61192106047320064
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [status] => 61185038284357632
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [status] => 61182890951720960
        )

)
```

array2

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [status] => 61185038284357632
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [status] => 61182890951720960
        )

)
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Define difference do you need all differences or if array1[0] == array2[0] do you need to print the difference.  Show some code you tried.  Whats your algorithm for searching the arrays...

Comment: How exactly do you define difference? Set difference, symmetric difference, must elements have same array posision, ...? What do you expect the result to be?

Comment: the first array is with fresh results, second one is for comparte the values not the index, i need to get difference between arrays and put result into db, expecting [status] => 61192106047320064 from fisrt array.

Comment: Check the comments at http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php for multidimensional array diff.

Comment: What's the problem with array_diff?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does array_diff on arrays of arrays return an empty array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955623/why-does-array-diff-on-arrays-of-arrays-return-an-empty-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but can't you just do something like this for your specific problem?

```
$newStatuses = array();

foreach($array1 as $element1) {
    foreach($array2 as $element2) {
        if($element1['status'] == $element2['status']) {
            continue 2;
        }
    }

    $newStatuses[] = $element1;
}
```

Each element of $newStatuses will be an array with a 'status' element from array1 that was not in array2.

So, $newStatuses would be this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [status] => 61192106047320064
        )

)
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php),

> This function only checks one dimension of a n-dimensional array. Of course you can check deeper dimensions by using array_diff($array1[0], $array2[0]);.

Therefore you cannot diff the second dimension of these arrays directly.

Instead, maybe you can extract the `status` values with [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php), save as two 1-dimensional arrays, and then `array_diff`. If you have multiple keys, use a for loop.

Answer (score -1):

have a look at this code, its part of cakephp but you may be able to adapt / rip it out

https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/cake/libs/set.php#L792

and the docs

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1496/diff