# Difference of two file arrays and finding unique between them

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 files file1.txt and file2.txt both files contains some email ids ,
i have converted the data of both files in different arrays i want the difference between 2 arrays.

for example `array1(a,b,c,d)`

```
array2(a,b)
```

output:

```
array3(c,d)
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you asked google about this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [array difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750475/array-difference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this..

```
    <?php
       $array1 = array("a" => "green", "red", "blue", "yellow");
       $array2 = array("b" => "green", "red", "yellow");
       $result = array_diff($array1, $array2);

       print_r($result);
        ?>

    Array
(
    [1] => blue
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use

```
$result = array_diff($array1,$array2);
```

Answer (score 0):

use `array_diff(array1,array2)` function

```
$a1=array();
$a2=array();
$result=array_diff($a1,$a2);
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

array marge and return unique array

```
$array1=array();
$array2=array();
    $array = array_unique (array_merge ($array1, $array2));
```