# Check which day is not avaliable in PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array which consists of 7 days names. This array will be dynamic everytime. So i want to check which day is missing from an array. For ex,

[Monday,Tuesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday]

Here, the wednesday is missing so output should be wednesday

Sometimes there will be more then one day will be missing and sometimes none, so the output should be and array which will contain all missing days.

Comment: Show your code???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [array difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750475/array-difference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can compare two arrays with `array_diff`. Example: https://3v4l.org/4g00a

Answer (score 2):

You can use **array_diff** function to get missing days.

```
$days = ['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday'];
$inputDays = ['Sunday','Friday'];
$missingDays = array_diff($days,$inputDays);
print_r($missingDays);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Monday
    [1] => Tuesday
    [2] => Wednesday
    [3] => Thursday
    [5] => Saturday
)
```

**array_diff** is case sensitive, you may need to convert string to lower case.

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/20RPZ)

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged both [js](/questions/tagged/js) and [php](/questions/tagged/php) but didn't specify which language you're using for this part of your code, here's a JS solution (which doesn't have a handy `array_diff` function)

```
var days = ["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"];
var input = ["Sunday","Friday"];
return days.filter(function(day) {return input.indexOf(day) < 0;});
```